# How to use Apache Camel to fit this messaging logic?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm using the Apache Camel DSL and trying to figure out how to route a message, like so.  Here's the logic, without any Camel DSL.

- Message enters queue
- Call bean
- If bean doesn't have exception

  - Call another bean with original message

My issue is that I'm not sure how to get to step 3.a using the original message.  The call to bean changes the message.  I can use a multicast, two pipelines, and header variables, but from what I can tell those header variables are in scope within a pipeline.

Any ideas are appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multicast eip in sequence mode

```
<from uri="somewhere"/>
<multicast>
  <to uri="bean:beanA"/>
  <to uri="bean:beanB"/>
</multicast>
```

The multicast runs in sequence mode by default, so first invoking beanA. And if that is a success, it invokes beanB, but with the original message (a copy of the same message that we called beanA with).

You can read about the multicast EIP here: http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html

Comment: Thanks.  My bean returns output that I need to run xsl on, though.  Won't that override the original message?

Comment: I now have a multicast with two pipelines.  I set some header vars in the first pipeline, but they are needed in the second.  They aren't in scope there, however.  I can't find any info on the scope of those variables.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you bean return anything, if its a void method, you can just call without the multicast. Then the message body is not altered. And in beanA you can still add new headers etc.

Answer (score 1):

from your 2nd bean, just call `exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()`

Comment: Thanks. My bean does not do any routing, though. Can I get the original message in the Spring DSL?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing the content of the message in a variable and setting the message back to that content after it was changed, like so...

```
<!-- store original content in header variable -->
<camel:setHeader headerName="marc"><camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple></camel:setHeader>
<!-- run some logic, output gets saved as another header variable, message as this point is now that output -->
<camel:bean ref="getPidsForUpdate"/>
<camel:setHeader headerName="pids"><camel:simple>${body}</camel:simple></camel:setHeader>
```

....set a bunch of variables based on that output, and then

```
<!-- get original message to run some more logic-->
<camel:setBody><camel:simple>${headers.marc}</camel:simple></camel:setBody>
```